# Swift JSON tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, populate

I'm really struggling to parse this JSON (https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y) and populate a tableview with the "**Date**" text, "**Event**" text, "**Hasta**" text and "**Location**" text. I realize this is probably easy for a non-newb. Here's my probably terrible code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var vigoData = [String]()


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible


    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 52.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y")!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in


        if let urlContent = data {


            do {

           let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

                if let eventData = jsonResult["Collection2"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    for event in eventData {

                        if let _ = event["Event"] as? String {

                            self.vigoData.append("text")

                        }


                    }


                }

                print(self.vigoData)

            } catch {

                print("JSON Serialization failed")

            }

        }


    }

    task.resume()

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to split your task in few steps and try to fix each step at a time: 1) Extract the data you need in a data structure (array of tuples), 2) Use the data structure to fill in your table cells

Comment: Care to explain this more in-depth please with examples? I'm an amateur

Comment: For example try parsing the JSON document and extract the desired values in an Array of tuples. You can follow this tutorial to learn how to work with JSON in Swift: http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial ; Here is another tutorial about tuples: http://www.raywenderlich.com/115300/swift-2-tutorial-part-3-tuples-protocols-delegates-and-table-views

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo `Collection2` vs. `collection2` but the main problem that there is a key `results`at the top level of the JSON dictionary which contains the dictionary `collection2`

```
…    
let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
let results =  jsonResult["results"] as! [String: AnyObject]
if let collection2 = results["collection2"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
  for eventData in collection2 {
    print(eventData["Location"]!)
    print(eventData["Hasta"]!)
    if let event = eventData["Event"] as? [String: String] {
      // self.vigoData.append("text")
      print(event["text"]!)
    }
  }
}
…
```

PS: There is no `Date` key in `collection2`