# Parse JSON Swift Subscript Error

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview, subscript

I'm trying to parse some JSON in swift and I'm getting a 'subscript' error. I've tried to cast as AnyObject instead of NSDictinary to no avail. Pretty stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 52.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]


    let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else {

            if let data = data {

             //print(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

                do { let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary


                    if jsonResult!.count > 0 {


                        if let items = jsonResult["Date"] as? NSArray {


                            print(items)


                        }




                    }


                } catch {



                }

        }


    }


}


    task.resume()


}
```

Comment: I answered almost the same question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302547/swift-json-tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, don't bite my head off, but is is possible that there is no "Date" key in jsonResult? That's how I would interpret a "subscript" error.

Also, when I fetch the data from the URL you are using, there is no "Date" object.

*...later...*

Don, here's what I whipped out to accomplish what you asked for in your most recent comment:

```
// JSONTest
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    var events: [EventRecord] = []

    // MARK: Types
    struct EventRecord {

        struct Event {
            let href: NSURL?
            let text: String?
        }

        let event: Event
        let hasta: String?
        let location: String?
    }

    // MARK: View lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 52.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]

        let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y")!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                print(error)

            } else {

                if let data = data {

                    //print(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

                    do {

                        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                        if jsonResult!.count > 0 {

                            if let results = jsonResult!["results"] as? NSDictionary, collection2 = results["collection2"] as? NSArray {

                                for entry in collection2 {
                                    if let dict = entry as? NSDictionary {
                                        self.events.append(self.processEntryDict(dict))
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        // BARF!
                                    }
                                }

                                print("events:\(self.events)")
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("In catch block")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    // MARK: Helper methods

    /// processEntryDict creates an `EventRecord` from the individual entry passed to the method and returns it to the caller.
    func processEntryDict(entry:  NSDictionary) -> EventRecord {

        // Each object in the "collection2" array is a dictionary of the form:
        //    {
        //        "Event": {
        //            "href": "http://www.vigolowcost.com/event/ceos-e-mares-de-felipe-aranda/?instance_id=31511",
        //            "text": "“Ceos e Mares” de Felipe Aranda"
        //        },
        //        "Hasta": "oct 23 todo el día",
        //        "Location": "Detrás do Marco, Vigo",
        //        "index": 2,
        //        "url": "http://www.vigolowcost.com/agenda/"
        //    },
        //

        let hasta = entry["Hasta"] as? String
        let location = entry["Location"] as? String

        var eventHref: NSURL?
        var eventText: String?

        if let eventDict = entry["Event"] as? NSDictionary {
            if let hrefText = eventDict["href"] as? String {
                eventHref = NSURL(string: hrefText)
            }

            eventText = eventDict["text"] as? String
        }

        let eventRecordEvent = EventRecord.Event(href: eventHref, text: eventText)
        return EventRecord(event: eventRecordEvent, hasta: hasta, location: location)
    }

}
```

Notice that I added stuff to ensure "results" and "collection2" exist, and then provide a means to traverse the entries in "collection2."

I've now written the class closer to the way I would if I were doing what I think you are trying to do. Though, I would also pull the completionHandler of the `session.dataTaskWithURL` call out into its own method.

Here are a few things to notice:

- I use `// MARK: xxx` to segregate functionality. These comments result in named dividers in the class identifier dropdown in Xcode. *(see below)* [image: named dividers screen shot]
- I created an `EventRecord` struct to hold the information about each event. This will make it much easier to interact with the array of events, as it is now a Swift `Array` of `EventRecord` objects. (The property named, `events`.) This also allows you to automatically leverage all the strict type-checking Swift provides.
- I process each entry in `collection2` using the new `processEntryDict(:)` function. This is another way I attempted to keep the code modular, with shorter methods. This eases testing, maintenance, documentation, and troubleshooting.
- The line before the declaration of `processEntryDict` is a special markup (note the three slashes). If you OPT-click on `processEntryDict`, you'll notice the description I put in there. This stuff was super powerful with Objective-C. I'm unsure whether it is as useful with Swift.
- For now, when you run the program, it spews the array of events to the debug console. Obviously, you're going to want to do something other than that with the event list, but this should give you a good headstart on moving your project forward.

Let me know if you need more help or if you want me to explain any of it to you.

I'm leaving the image of the first bit of the contents of "collection2" here, because it serves as a good reference.

[image: screen shot of 'capture2' array]

Comment: Thanks Matt, certainly won't bit your head off, I appreciate the help. OK, now here's my dumb question: what valid keys can you see? I would like to test, I tried 'Event" - still an error. :)

Comment: You might try "collection2". It seems to have an array of Event objects. So you'd do something like `jsonResult!["collection2"]["Event"]`. Unfortunately, I can't make it work in a playground, and I need to run out to an appointment, so I don't have time to whip up a full-on project.

Comment: Actually, though, I'd think you'd want to do `jsonResult!["collection2"] as? NSArray` and iterate through that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. :) Really appreciate it.. will see if it works now. Hope you're around if it fails haha

Comment: I'll be back in a few hours. If you haven't figured it out, I'll dig in further.

Comment: Still nothing with collection2 :( There's no output :(

Comment: K. I'll play around with it if you haven't resolved it by the time I return.

Comment: Thanks. Can't crack it :)

Comment: Okay, Don, I'm back. Let me see if I can provide some help before I hit the sack.

Comment: Don, I believe I've got it solved for you. I edited my original answer. As I say in that answer, if you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Wow, thanks Matt - I couldn't be more grateful. Thanks for all the effort... Can you explain the contents part please? I want to extract Hasta, Location & Event.

Comment: Don, you should be all set. Again, let me know if I can help you more.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt.. That's very very helpful of you. Really appreciate it!